# java.lang.NullPointerException - error when logout Android

Tags: java, android

I followed this tutorial (http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/) for creating member system with login and logout feature. The problem is when logout it doesn't work. I'm creating logout in Fragment Navigation Drawer Menu.

This My Activity.

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener {

private static String TAG = HomeActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private Toolbar mToolbar;
private FragmentDrawer drawerFragment;

private SQLiteHandler db;
private SessionManager session;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);


    drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
    drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);
    drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);

    // display the first navigation drawer view on app launch
    displayView(0);
}



private void displayView(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_home);
            break;
        case 1:
            captureImage();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new ReportsFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_reports);
            break;
        case 3:
            title = getString(R.string.title_settings);
            break;
        case 4:
            logoutUser();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        // set the toolbar title
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }
}


private void logoutUser() {
    session.setLogin(false);
    db.deleteUsers();
    // Launching the login activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
}
```

And this is error log.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.company.report.activity.HomeActivity.logoutUser(HomeActivity.java:251)
        at com.company.report.activity.HomeActivity.displayView(HomeActivity.java:124)
        at com.company.report.activity.HomeActivity.onDrawerItemSelected(HomeActivity.java:99)
        at com.company.report.activity.FragmentDrawer$1.onClick(FragmentDrawer.java:79)
        at com.company.report.activity.FragmentDrawer$RecyclerTouchListener.onInterceptTouchEvent(FragmentDrawer.java:160)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchOnItemTouchIntercept(RecyclerView.java:1986)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView.java:2027)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1629)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1912)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1371)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2364)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1860)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:5721)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:2890)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2466)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.processInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:845)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2475)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `session`and `db` are never initialized. Initialize it and the error will be gone.